# calculate cummulative sum in azure stream analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

Is it possible to calculate the cummulative sum over groups in azure stream analytics?

This is the input:

```
TMS                       product      amount
2023-06-01 10:00:00          P1          10
2023-06-01 10:00:20          P2          40
2023-06-01 10:00:25          P2          30
2023-06-01 10:01:05          P1          20
2023-06-01 10:01:20          P2          60
2023-06-01 10:01:25          P1          70
```

This should be the output;

```
TMS                       product      cum_sum
2023-06-01 10:00:00          P1          10
2023-06-01 10:00:20          P2          40
2023-06-01 10:00:25          P2          70
2023-06-01 10:01:05          P1          30
2023-06-01 10:01:20          P2          140
2023-06-01 10:01:25          P1          100
```

Unfortunately I have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to calculate the cumulative sum over groups in Azure Stream Analytics. You can use the  `PARTITION BY`  clause in combination with the  `SUM`  function to achieve this.

Here is the query that produces the desired output based on the input you provided.

**Query:**

```
SELECT
TMS, product,  SUM(amount)  OVER  (PARTITION  BY product LIMIT  DURATION  (minute, 5))  AS cum_sum
into 
output
FROM
input
```

`LIMIT DURATION` clause specifies how much history from the current row is included in the group. Since the sample input data is within five minutes, I have given `limit duration (minute,5)` in the above query.

**Input:**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]

**Reference**: [OVER (Azure Stream Analytics) - Stream Analytics Query | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/over-azure-stream-analytics)